# Extract year and elapsed year from a string in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm having a hard time to get all the years from a string.

The string will is look like this

```
this is a sample January 2017, this is a sample June 12, 2018. This is a sample October 18, 2018.
```

I want to retrieve all the **years** from the paragraph then get the elapsed year from it, for example.

**since you have 2017 and 2018 in the list, the elapsed year would be 1 year.**

Thank you for your help!

Edit:

Thank you @alive for the answer. This solves my problem

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{4}/', preg_replace('/\s+/','', $experience), $matches);
            $years_array = array_values(array_unique($matches[0]));
            sort($years_array);
            $difference = end($years_array)-$years_array[0];
            echo $difference.' years';
```

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: yes year always increased.

Comment: Do you want to return 1 year even if it's `december 2018, January 2019`?

Comment: Do you want the month too, i mean the full date?

Comment: @Andreas yes only 1 year

Comment: Only the year is enough, but if months is possible it will be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php built-in functions for that:

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{4}/', $str, $matches);
$years_array = array_values(array_unique($matches[0]));
sort($years_array);
$difference = end($years_array)-$years_array[0];
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/ZLtWU

Comment: preg_match_all('/[0-9]{4}/', preg_replace('/\s+/','', $experience), $matches);
    $years_array = array_values(array_unique($matches[0]));
    sort($years_array);
    $difference = end($years_array)-$years_array[0];
    echo $difference.' years';

i edited your answer to remove spaces in the string. and it works fine! Thank you so much for the big help

Comment: @kiogipaya so you have given up on months?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, year is enough. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you do want the months then you can just add the months to the regex and use strtotime and date to calculate the difference.
Because we get the seconds elapsed between the two dates date will return a date from 1970. So subtract 1970 and you get the years.

```
$str = 'this is a sample January 2017, this is a sample June 12, 2019. This is a sample October 18, 2018.';
preg_match_all('/(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December).*?([0-9]{4})/', $str, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $m){
    $new[] = strtotime($m);
}

sort($new);
$difference = end($new)-$new[0];
$years =  date("Y", $difference)-1970;
$months =  date("n", $difference);

echo $years . ' years and ' . $months . ' months'; // 2 years and 6 months.
```

https://3v4l.org/RqPaC